# Is there a limit to how many queries you can do in certain time in Node RestApi

Tags: node.js, api, rest, rally

I am trying to get Project permission for users and trying to set the permission later. The project and user map has 89866 objects. It errors out after its done with not more than 300.

```
Error:
 {
         "code": "ECONNRESET",
         "errno": "ECONNRESET",
         "syscall": "read"
 }

    return _.reduce(projectHash, function(promise, teamPermission, projectOID){
        return promise.then(function(){
            return rallyUtil.getProjectPermission('/user/' + userOID, '/project/' + projectOID).then(function(permission){
                if(!permission || (permission.Role != teamPermission && permission.Role != 'Admin')){
                    //need to get user or else WSAPI server will throw a concurrency error
                    return rallyUtil.getUser('/user/' + userOID).then(function(){
                        return rallyUtil.setProjectPermission('/user/' + userOID, '/project/' + projectOID, teamPermission);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no limit for the number of requests you send, or on promises. however this happens in two different cases:

## possible case 1

reduce and promises are heavy on memory. so node might run out of memory, but i doubt this is the case.

## possible case 2

> if the server is overloaded it simply kills the connection as a result. hence you get ECONNRESET.

no server can handle 89866 requests in less than seconds, you need to have a delay every few or send them in batches.

Answer (score 0):

There is not generally a limit on the service side.  It seems like you are probably making more requests in your node app than is strictly necessary however.  We've seen some strange behavior with chaining enormous numbers of promises together.  Is it possible to reduce the overall number of requests your app is making?